# Merge two laravel projects

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I have two admin panels created on laravel 5.2 project. They both are of different purpose. I mean to say that they both have different functionalities.

I want both panels to be in one project. Is there any method to join/merge two laravel projects into single project?

The idea is to have two dashboards in one project instead of creating everything from scratch.

Kindly share idea or tell any short method to save time.

Comment: For this question more information is required. What you tried? any code? any steps?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham
Sometimes you ask in general way 
Onix is smart in understanding my problem
But anyhow thx
Onix helped me out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically,

If you are using the same version of Laravel. you can merge manually by moving the files you edited, for example the models, controllers, any middleware, your views, migrations, any files in the public folder you need.

And step by step you will eventually merge them.

Comment: thx **Onix** 
i followed your way and got success !